# AppEngine WebService authentication handling

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm doing a JSON WebService backend for an iPhone application. Is there any best practice or existing frameworks (I use Python) to handle authentication and keeping a session between requests? I guess you use some form of ticket system because you can't use regular sessions like with web browsers?

Comment: Are you planning to support other auth service providers like FB, Twitter? Or just stick to Google accounts?

Comment: At the moment I will not use any of those, I will use my own authentication method with unique device id. But I might want to add the option to sign in through FB, Twitter or Google accounts in the future.

Comment: In that case OAuth is your friend, but be careful because Google doesn't automatically handle third party OAuth providers via their auth system, you will have to implement this yourself. We have some code we are likely to open source to help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely go for [Oauth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oauth).

Have a look to the [gtm-oauth](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/) library, it allows Cocoa applications to sign in to services using OAuth for authentication and authorization and it works with Google APIs and with any standard OAuth provider.

Check [this](http://googlemac.blogspot.com/2010/09/oauth-sign-in-controllers-for-ios-and.html) blog post for further information.

Comment: Is Oauth appropriate even if I have my own authentication through unique device id? And I will not make my application data available to other applications, isn't that one of the main purposes with Oauth?

Comment: Imo you should never build an authentication mechanism on something that can be easily spoofed like the UDID.

Comment: Also you might want to consider OAuth2, if you want to support other providers.

Comment: But given that I don't want to use an external authentication provider, is there any reason to use Oauth then? Does it provide some authentication, ticket handling or other functionality needed even if no third party is included?